# Point domain to new host - changed nameservers, now what?

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver

This is driving me nuts, because I know I'm missing something simple. I've read numerous articles/posts about how to point (not transfer) your domain to a new web host. They all say to change the name server settings at your old host, so here is what I did:

On old host (1and1.com) changed the name server settings to those of my new host (inmotionhosting.com) like below:

Domain name :   mydomain.com 
Name server 1:  ns.inmotionhosting.com 
Name server 2:  ns2.inmotionhosting.com

... and confirmed this is active (did it a couple days ago)

This is where every post/article I've found stops. They imply this is all that needs to be done.

But how does the new host know to point the domain to my account, and the directory in my account I want it work from??

There's go to be something else to be done - just pointing to the generic name servers of the new host can't be all there is to it.

Thanks in advance...I'm bewildered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this support article](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/cpanel-manage-domains/new-domains-add-on-parked-and-subdomains) from your new hosts support site discusses the different kinds of domains you can add via their cpanel (parked, addon etc) and there is also a tutioral on [adding an addon domain](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/cpanel-manage-domains/adding-add-on-domain-in-cpanel) (which is what I suspect you need to do).

Let us know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thanks. The add-on domain was the 'secret sauce' I was missing!

Answer (score 3):

Larry you need to add the domain to your new host.
If you are using cPanel, then there would be a option for you to add the addondomain.
Over there add the domain name and the directory from where you want the domain to run.
If the newly added domain is pointing to your new host name servers, then it will start running from the directory you specified.

Answer (score 1):

What domain name did you specify when you set up the new account?

If you are simply moving from one hosting company to another then when you set up your new account you should have specified the domain that you wanted to use at that stage. This is how the new host knows to point the domain to your account (when it starts receiving requests). Even though the domain will still have been pointing to your old host (and sending requests to your old host).

You then change the nameservers on the domain to point to the new host. The new host then starts receiving requests and knows what to do with them since the new host knows the name of the domain.

If you specified a different domain name when you set up the new hosting account then you will probably need to set up an additional parked or addon domain in your new hosting account (if that is supported) - as the other answers have mentioned.